# Replacing instructions in LLVM IR

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I wrote a code that replaces the add instructions in the LLVM IR with sub instructions by creating Value*. I'm trying to replace `%inc = add i8 %2, 1` with `%5 = sub i8 0, %4`.

My question is how to make the change appear in the LLVM IR file? I can print the new Value* on the screen but not in my LLVM IR file.

```
      for (auto &B : F) {
     for (BasicBlock::iterator DI = B.begin(); DI != B.end(); ) {
      Instruction *Inst = &*DI++;

      if (auto *op = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&*Inst)) {
        // Insert at the point where the instruction `op` appears.
        IRBuilder<> builder(op);
 std::string opcd,opcd_change;
opcd=Inst->getOpcodeName();
        // Make a multiply with the same operands as `op`.
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

if (opcd=="add"){
errs() <<"instruction ";
Inst->print(errs());
//errs() <<'\n'<<"instruction opcode changed"<<opcd_change<<'\n';
errs() <<" instruction opcode "<<opcd<<'\n';
        Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);


         Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);
          Instruction* neg = BinaryOperator::CreateNeg(rhs);

errs() <<"instruction opcode changed "<<opcd_change<<'\n';
Instruction* newInst = BinaryOperator::CreateSub(lhs, neg, "test");
errs() << "NewInst:\n" << *newInst << "\n";
    ReplaceInstWithInst(op,newInst);
    errs()<< "Instruction replaced ";
    errs() <<'\n'<<'\n';
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

I cannot comprehend what the error means. I am fairly new to LLVM so I do not get what it means.

**Edit shows the error after using ReplaceInstWithInst **

```
'opt: /home/zainub/llvm/lib/Transforms/Utils/BasicBlockUtils.cpp:211: void llvm::ReplaceInstWithInst(llvm::BasicBlock::InstListType&, llvm::BasicBlock::iterator&, llvm::Instruction*): Assertion `I->getParent() == nullptr && "ReplaceInstWithInst: Instruction already inserted into basic block!"' failed.
#0 0x00000000027abd3a llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x27abd3a)
#1 0x00000000027ac08e PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x27ac08e)
#2 0x00000000027aa4e6 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x27aa4e6)
#3 0x00000000027ab687 SignalHandler(int) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x27ab687)
#4 0x00007fbb71d32d10 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x10d10)
#5 0x00007fbb71160267 gsignal (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x35267)
#6 0x00007fbb71161eca abort (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x36eca)
#7 0x00007fbb7115903d (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2e03d)
#8 0x00007fbb711590f2 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2e0f2)
#9 0x00000000027cfa1c llvm::ReplaceInstWithInst(llvm::SymbolTableList<llvm::Instruction>&, llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::Instruction>&, llvm::Instruction*) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x27cfa1c)
#10 0x00000000027cfb2b llvm::ReplaceInstWithInst(llvm::Instruction*, llvm::Instruction*) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x27cfb2b)
#11 0x00007fbb70f1d027 (anonymous namespace)::Fundep::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) /home/zainub/llvm/lib/Transforms/Fundep/Fundep.cpp:161:0
#12 0x0000000002246841 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x2246841)
#13 0x00000000022469f8 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x22469f8)
#14 0x0000000002246db5 (anonymous namespace)::MPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x2246db5)
#15 0x0000000002247539 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x2247539)
#16 0x0000000002247779 llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x2247779)
#17 0x00000000010583e9 main (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x10583e9)
#18 0x00007fbb7114ba40 __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a40)
#19 0x0000000001033119 _start (/usr/local/bin/opt+0x1033119)
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/local/bin/opt -load /home/zainub/build/lib/LLVMFundep.so -Fundep 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '<stdin>'.
2.  Running pass 'Fundep Pass' on function '@main'
```

Aborted (core dumped)

Edit-2

Generated IR which is problematic

```
instruction   %add115 = add i64 %86, 20 instruction opcode add
NewInst:
  %test = sub i64 %86, <badref>
op   %add115 = add i64 %86, 20
Instruction replaced   %test = sub i64 %86, <badref>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [ReplaceInstWithInst](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a58cb353f6bb490b0c689f5f2a830414d) instead?

Comment: I am very new to it so I am just trying. I have to replace add instruction with a subtract instruction. In this case I have Value*  sub which has my new instruction. How can I use Value* in ReplaceInstWithInst? Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your snippet doesn't work, but in any case, the canonical way to replace one instruction with another is using [ReplaceInstWithInst](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a58cb353f6bb490b0c689f5f2a830414d).

`Instruction` sublasses `Value` and `BinaryOperation` subclasses `Instruction`, so the first argument to ReplaceInstWithInst will just be your `op`. The second argument should be the return value of CreateSub - you can dyn_cast it to an `Instruction` and it will likely succeed.

There's a chance CreateSub will return something which isn't an instruction, though, in case the compiler managed to fold your newly-created instruction to something simpler (e.g. a constant). If this case is a concern for you, use [ReplaceInstWithValue](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a61aae2c2da42995f55a12f0467e3053f) instead, passing it your `B->getInstList()` and `DI`.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the error after using ReplaceInstWithInst. Please check.

Comment: @MBaloch The problem is that the instruction you provide as the second argument to ReplaceInstWithInst is already placed within some basic block. If you update the code in your question I could take a look at it.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry Oak, I just checked your reply as I was busy working on another module, I have updated the code. The error still remains the same

Comment: @MBaloch the problem is that you've created the new instruction via a Builder, which automatically inserts it into some basic block. Create it instead using something that doesn't add it anywhere, such as `BinaryOperator::Create` (or one of its short versions, such as [CreateNUWSub](http://llvm.org/test-doxygen/api/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#ab44e55480b59b60fa22de6de2c91f5bf))

Comment: Okay I am going to try it, but the point is, if the instruction is already inserted then why can't I see it?

Comment: @MBaloch you should be able to see it, have you tried using dump()? Just printing to IR is problematic because the new instruction has no uses, so some pass might drop it on the way. In any case, the error reported is from the ReplaceInstWithInst call, which is later than the insertion.

Comment: I have pasted the portion which my instruction is printed

Comment: @MBaloch your neg instruction is not added anywhere, ReplaceInstWithInst only inserts the instruction you directly give it, not the transitive closure of other instructions it needs... hence the badref. So the neg needs to be placed in the basic block (with a builder as you did before, or with the constructor variant which accepts an instruction), while the sub needs to be created with no container, as you correctly did with the BinaryOperator::CreateSub() call.

Comment: okay thanks. now there is no error but there is still no replacement of instructions in the LLVM IR :(

Comment: My code started working turned out I was not writing it to the bitcode file properly, rest everything was okay :) I'm really really thankful to you, Oak. Rock on! :)